# Not able to create a topic on stand alone Kafka broker

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to create a new topic on Kafka server. but getting below error.
Please not its a stand-alone system where there is only one broker set up.
It was working fine earlier , what i changed is just new topic name to be created. Whats wrong all of sudden ? and how it worked earlier ?

```
/usr/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0# bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test00
Error while executing topic command : replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0
[2016-01-25 15:42:59,115] ERROR kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0
```

Thank you.
~Sha

Comment: Why available broker is 0?need more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replication factor needs to be of at most the number of brokers you have in your cluster - 1, this is how replication works. [kafka-replication](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Replication)

In your example --replication-factor should be zero.

Comment: I have one more problem in understanding these kafka message streams Getting error like below.ZookeeperConsumerConnector can create message streams at most once
 at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:78)
 at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:96)
 at com.steelwedge.consumer.ConsumerController.executeEntityConsumers(ConsumerController.java:100)
 at com.steelwedge.consumer.ConsumerController.main(ConsumerController.java:180)

Comment: I am not sure about that stack trace, probably you should create a new question explaining more about the problem